# Protractor tests in CoffeeScript producing "SyntaxError: unexpected by"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to write the following [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) test in CoffeeScript:

```
describe "tests", ->

  browser.get "/"

  it "should display Login page", ->
    expect(element(by.css("h1")).getText()).toBe "Login"
```

However, CoffeeScript spits out this error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected by

Solutions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like @meagar said it is reserved, you can alias it in your protractor config in the `onPrepare` block:

```
require('coffee-script/register');

exports.config = {
  ....

  // by is reserved in coffee script
  onPrepare: function() {
    global.By = global.by;
  }
}
```

then

```
expect(element(By.css("h1")).getText()).toBe "Login"
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just had a look at the Protractor source code, and it seems that `By` is already an alias. :) See: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ad33da8ecc76322cee36a7344042a52ff33c280c/lib/runner.js#L176

Answer (score 3):

`by` is a reserved word in CoffeeScript, used in specifying loop increments:

```
evens = (x for x in [0..10] by 2)
```

Use a different variable name.